# Partial Harmonic Sum Equals $1/\Pi(1-1/p)$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory, products

Given $n\in \mathbb{N}$, I would like to know why (preferably with an algebraic or analytic argument)
$$\bigg(\Pi_{p\le n,\,p\, \text{prime}}(1-1/p)\bigg)\sum_{i}1/i=1,$$
where the sum is over all $i=2^{a_2}3^{a_3}\cdots p^{a_p}$ with $a_i\ge 0.$

This equation is due to the fact that $\bigg(\Pi_{p\le n,\,p\, \text{prime}}(1-1/p)\bigg)1/i=\mathbb{P}(X=i)$, where $X=\Pi_{p\le n}p^{Z_p}$, $Z_p$ are independent, geometric variables with $\mathbb{P}(Z_p=k)=(1-1/p)1/p^k$.

Comment: Show by induction or using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic that $$\prod_{p \le k} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \prod_{p \le k} (1+p^{-s}+(p^2)^{-s}+\ldots) = \sum_{n \in A_k} n^{-s}$$ where $A_k$ is the set of integers whose prime factors are $ \le k$ (letting $k \to \infty$ you obtain the Euler product for the Riemann zeta function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the power series expansion, valid for $|x| \lt 1$: $$\frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \ldots$$

which means that $$1 - \frac{1}{p} = \left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p}}\right)^{-1} = \left(1 + \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + \frac{1}{p^3} + \ldots\right)^{-1}.$$

We therefore have the product $$\prod\limits_{\substack{p \leq n \\ p\text{ prime}}}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) = \left(\prod\limits_{\substack{p \leq n \\ p\text{ prime}}}\left(1 + \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + \frac{1}{p^3} + \ldots\right)\right)^{-1}.$$

The fundamental theorem of arithmetic says that every integer has a unique prime factorization, and so every positive integer divisible only by the primes not larger than $n$ will occur exactly once in the set $\{2^{a_2}3^{a_3} \ldots p^{a_p}: a_i \in \mathbb{N}\}$ (where $p$ is the largest prime $\leq n$).

But each of these terms also occurs exactly once in the denominators in the given product after using the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), which can be done since the series are absolutely convergent and there are finitely many of them.

Intuitively, applying the distributive property, you will find the term $\frac{1}{2^{a_2}3^{a_3}\ldots p^{a_p}}$ occuring due to multiplying the $a_2$-th term of the series for $(1 + 1/2 + 1/2^2 + \ldots)$, the $a_3$-th term of the series for $(1 + 1/3 + 1/3^2 + \ldots)$, ..., the $a_p$-th term of the series for $(1 + 1/p + 1/p^2 + \ldots)$ (counting from $0$, so $\frac{1}{p_i^k}$ is the $k$-th term of the series summing over the $i$-th prime $p_i$).

That means $$\prod\limits_{\substack{p \leq n \\ p\text{ prime}}}\left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right) = \left(\sum\limits_{a_i \in \mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^{a_2}3^{a_3}\ldots p^{a_p}}\right)^{-1}$$ which is what you observed.

Comment: This is similar to how one could derive the Euler product for the Riemann $\zeta$ function, disregarding questions of convergence for infinite products.